# Pandas transform dataframe using groupby when count of a string in a column is maximum

Tags: python

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID        IndentNo      Status     System_text
162       1000025418    Reject     Short Description Error
162       1000025418    Reject     Delivery date Error
162       1000025418    Accept
```

As we can see that for a single `ID` we have two different `Status` viz `Reject` and `Accept`.

Objective: I want this dataframe to be transformed in a way that *if count of `Reject` is more than count of `Accept`, then final df should read as* :

```
ID        IndentNo      Status           System_text
162       1000025418    Reject     Short Description Error, Deivery Date Error
```

When I am trying the following:

```
df_f = df_final.groupby(['IndentId','IndentNo'])['status'].agg(max).reset_index(name='system_message')
```

I am getting the following `df`:

```
ID        IndentNo      System_text
162       1000025418    Reject
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: 'max' finds the maximum value, not the most common value (known as the mode)

Comment: @PaulH: it gives me the correct answer. However, I am losing `system_message` column values in a format as shown as desired output.

Comment: That's just a coincidence in this case.

Comment: OK then can you please throw some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` to get the count of each `Accept` and `Reject` in the series.

If you have more rejects than accepts, join the `System_text` of all the rejects, and return this result as a single row dataframe. Otherwise, just return the original dataframe.

```
def transform_rejects(df):
    counts = df['Status'].value_counts().to_dict()
    if counts.get('Reject', 0) > counts.get('Accept', 0):
        desc = ', '.join(df.loc[df['Status'].eq('Reject'), 'System_text'].tolist())
        return pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['Reject'], 'System_text': [desc]})
    return df

df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'IndentNo']).apply(transform_rejects)
df2.index = df2.index.droplevel(2)
>>> df2
                Status                                   System_text
ID  IndentNo                                                        
162 1000025418  Reject  Short Description Error, Delivery date Error
```